# textfield remotevalidation with ext.net 2.0 and mvc4 with razor syntax, how to set the action url of the controller

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, ext.net

I'm using ext.net 2.0 with mvc 4.
Because of a complete lack of examples there, I don't find
a way to set the url for the textfiels remotevalidation

```
Html.X().TextField()
    .Width(180)
    .IsRemoteValidation(true)
    .Value("Textfield1")
```

when using aspx, the code is :

```
<ext:TextField 
    ID="TextField2" 
    runat="server" 
    FieldLabel="Company" 
    AnchorHorizontal="92%"    
    AllowBlank="False" 
    IsRemoteValidation="true" 
    CausesValidation="true">
    <RemoteValidation 
        Url="~/Controller/CheckName" 
        Json="true" Delay="300" >
    </RemoteValidation>
</ext:TextField>
```

But there's nothing like RemoteValidation when using razor.....
Any ideas ?

Regards,
Holger

Answer (score 2):

> But there's nothing like RemoteValidation when using razor.....

It is fixed in v2.1 (2.1 is not released yet)
You can use the following code

```
Html.X().TextField().Control(c=>{c.RemoteValidation.Url = ...})
```